# Error al enviar la fecha y hora

Tags: java, mysql-workbench

tengo el siguiente caso:
Estoy enviando desde java la fecha (getIngFecha) de registro pero al momento que llega a la base de datos (MySQL) se guarda la fecha y la hora con "31/12/2019:00.00.00" para lo cual no llega la hora. Si ahy algo que me falta agregar pero no le atino aun :(

```
@Transactional("txManager")
    @Override
    public ResultadoDao guardarInventario(NotaIngreso inventario) throws ExceptionDao {
        ResultadoDao resultadoDao = new ResultadoDao();

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();        
        session.doWork(new Work() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Connection cnctn) throws SQLException {
                String sql = "{call SP_INV_INS_INVENTARIO(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
                try (CallableStatement callableStatement = cnctn.prepareCall(sql)) {
                    callableStatement.setInt(1,inventario.getIdEmpresa());
                    callableStatement.setInt(2, inventario.getIdSucursal());    
                    callableStatement.setString(3, inventario.getIngNumero());
                    callableStatement.setString(4, inventario.getIngDocumento());
                    callableStatement.setString(5, inventario.getIngPeriodo());
                    callableStatement.setString(6, inventario.getIngMes());
                    callableStatement.setString(7, inventario.getIngTipoIngreso());
                    callableStatement.setDate(8, new java.sql.Date(inventario.getIngFecha().getTime()));
                    callableStatement.setString(9, inventario.getResCodigo());
                    callableStatement.setString(10, inventario.getIngReferencia());
                    callableStatement.setString(11, inventario.getCiaId());
                    callableStatement.setString(12, inventario.getTmoCodigo());
                    callableStatement.setString(13, inventario.getAlmCodigo());
```

Comment: Que te regresa getIngFecha()? O más bien, que formato regresa?

Comment: solo la fecha ejm: 2020-02-05 00:00:00, pero no la hora que es lo que tambien me interesa

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas darle formato a tu fecha, algo como esto te debería de funcionar:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");  
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
```

**Recuerda que debes de agregar las librerías**

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;  
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
```